# Installing PECL in Cpanel (Fatal Error Class 'HttpRequest' not found )

Tags: php, api, cpanel, pecl

I need to call an API using PECL from my Server. I installed `PEAR and PECL` from the `PHP PEAR Packages in Cpanel.` .I attached the screenshot. But when I run my code `$request = new HttpRequest();` it returns an error `Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in /home/wonr/public_html/sms_api.php on line 3`
It is shared hosting.Is this causing because of the path error? Or do I need to do any additional setup on the Server?
I cannot find additional information on this.

Thank you.[image: installed packages(PEAR,PECL)]

Comment: Do you have WHM access or just cPanel acces?

Comment: Yes.I have WHM access.